# Python : Return the missing weekdays dates and assign rate next to missing date

Tags: python, pandas

```
Dates       rates
7/26/2019   1.04
7/30/2019   1.0116
7/31/2019   1.005
8/1/2019    1.035
8/2/2019    1.01
8/6/2019    0.9886
8/7/2019    1.0048
8/8/2019    0.97
8/9/2019    0.9659
8/12/2019   0.965
```

In the above dataframe, 29th July 2019 and 5th August 2019 are missing. These are weekdays. I need to populate the missing weekdays dates and assign the 'rate' which is next to missing date. For example: Assign the 30th july 2019 'rate' to the missing 29th july 2019 as well. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: please show us the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Please stop reposting practically identical questions over and over: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156375/python-pandas-return-the-consecutive-missing-weekdays-dates-and-assign-rate-ne, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152785/return-the-consecutive-missing-weekdays-dates-and-assign-rate-next-to-missing-da.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example `pd.offsets.BDay()` to get next business day.

Initial dataframe (the `Dates` column is of DateTime type):

```
       Dates   rates
0 2019-07-26  1.0400
1 2019-07-30  1.0116
2 2019-07-31  1.0050
3 2019-08-01  1.0350
4 2019-08-02  1.0100
5 2019-08-06  0.9886
6 2019-08-07  1.0048
7 2019-08-08  0.9700
8 2019-08-09  0.9659
9 2019-08-12  0.9650
```

Then:

```
df = df.merge(
        pd.DataFrame({'Dates':df['Dates'] + pd.offsets.BDay()}), on='Dates', how='outer'
    ).sort_values('Dates').bfill().dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        Dates   rates
0  2019-07-26  1.0400
1  2019-07-29  1.0116
2  2019-07-30  1.0116
3  2019-07-31  1.0050
4  2019-08-01  1.0350
5  2019-08-02  1.0100
6  2019-08-05  0.9886
7  2019-08-06  0.9886
8  2019-08-07  1.0048
9  2019-08-08  0.9700
10 2019-08-09  0.9659
11 2019-08-12  0.9650
```

Comment: Thanks my friend ! I got stuck pd.date_range earlier.

Comment: I used this code lately but found that it can impute 1 missing day with forward fill. How to fix the problem if 3 days are missing consequently and impute all three with forward fill.