# Return the consecutive missing weekdays dates and assign rate next to missing dates

Tags: python, pandas

```
Dates       rates
7/26/2019   1.04
7/30/2019   1.0116
7/31/2019   1.005
8/1/2019    1.035
8/2/2019    1.01
8/6/2019    0.9886
8/12/2019   0.965

df = df.merge(
    pd.DataFrame({'Dates':df['Dates'] + pd.offsets.BDay()}), on='Dates', how='outer'
).sort_values('Dates').bfill().dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

I tried the above code but its unable to fix the consecutive missing business days. It can fix only for 1 day. In the above dataframe, 29th July 2019 then 5th, 7th , 8th , 9th August are missing. These are weekdays. I need to populate the missing weekdays dates and assign the 'rate' which is next to missing date. For example: Assign the 30th july 2019 'rate' to the missing 29th july 2019 as well and so on for all missing dates. Please suggest. Thanks I expect the following output

```
Dates       rates
7/26/2019   1.04
7/29/2019   1.021
7/30/2019   1.0116
7/31/2019   1.005
8/1/2019    1.035
8/2/2019    1.01
8/5/2019    0.9886
8/6/2019    0.9886
8/7/2019    0.965
8/8/2019    0.965
8/8/2019    0.965
8/12/2019   0.965
```

Comment: Does this work `df.set_index('Dates').asfreq('B').ffill()`

Comment: Please elaborate. I tried but didnt work.

Comment: You did not include a description of what you think the final result should look like.  Therefore, I did not want to spend my time creating an answer (that would include more elaboration) on what is a guess.  It didn't work.  That means I guessed wrong.  Without an actual [mcve] I'll move on.

Comment: i have done like this     df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'Date':df['Date'] + pd.offsets.BDay()}), on='Date', how='outer').set_index('Date').asfreq('B').ffill().sort_values('Date') and got TypeError: must be str, not BusinessDay

Comment: I want to see your final expectation, in addition to what you've tried.  Also, it would be helpful to provide code that produces your dataframe.  As you have it, I can't tell if your `'Dates'` column are actually dates or strings that look like dates.

Comment: Please see my expectation of output as above.

Comment: What happened to `7/29/2019`?  Can you tell me what the dtype  of the `'Dates'` column is?  Run `df.Dates.dtype` and tell me that it returns.

Comment: Sorry. I missed 7/29/2019. dtype is dtype('O')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207537/discussion-between-akash-and-pirsquared).

Comment: Please don't [repost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156375/python-pandas-return-the-consecutive-missing-weekdays-dates-and-assign-rate-ne). Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: This question is also practically identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935043/python-return-the-missing-weekdays-dates-and-assign-rate-next-to-missing-date, making this and the one I shared previously the 2nd and 3rd duplicates respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try option 1 as below which includes creating a new df & merging it (the route you are already on)

or option 2 as suggested by @piRSquared (`bfill()` instead of `ffill()`)

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
a=pd.DataFrame({'Dates':pd.bdate_range('2019-07-26', '2019-08-12')})
df.merge(a, on='Dates', how='outer').sort_values('Dates').bfill().dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
        Dates   rates
0   2019-07-26  1.0400
1   2019-07-29  1.0116
2   2019-07-30  1.0116
3   2019-07-31  1.0050
4   2019-08-01  1.0350
5   2019-08-02  1.0100
6   2019-08-05  0.9886
7   2019-08-06  0.9886
8   2019-08-07  0.9650
9   2019-08-08  0.9650
10  2019-08-09  0.9650
11  2019-08-12  0.9650
```

```
df.set_index('Dates').asfreq('B').bfill().reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
         Dates  rates
0   2019-07-26  1.0400
1   2019-07-29  1.0116
2   2019-07-30  1.0116
3   2019-07-31  1.0050
4   2019-08-01  1.0350
5   2019-08-02  1.0100
6   2019-08-05  0.9886
7   2019-08-06  0.9886
8   2019-08-07  0.9650
9   2019-08-08  0.9650
10  2019-08-09  0.9650
11  2019-08-12  0.9650
```