# Python Pandas : Return the consecutive missing weekdays dates and assign rate next to missing dates in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
Dates       rates
7/26/2019   1.04
7/30/2019   1.0116
7/31/2019   1.005
8/1/2019    1.035
8/2/2019    1.01
8/6/2019    0.9886
8/12/2019   0.965

df = df.merge(
    pd.DataFrame({'Dates':df['Dates'] + pd.offsets.BDay()}), on='Dates', how='outer'
).sort_values('Dates').bfill().dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

I tried the above code but its unable to fix the consecutive missing business days. It can fix only for 1 day. In the above dataframe, 29th July 2019 then 5th, 7th , 8th , 9th August are missing. These are weekdays. I need to populate the missing weekdays dates and assign the 'rate' which is next to missing date. For example: Assign the 30th july 2019 'rate' to the missing 29th july 2019 as well and so on for all missing dates. Please suggest. Thanks I expect the following output

```
Dates       rates
7/26/2019   1.04
7/29/2019   1.0116
7/30/2019   1.0116
7/31/2019   1.005
8/1/2019    1.035
8/2/2019    1.01
8/5/2019    0.9886
8/6/2019    0.9886
8/7/2019    0.965
8/8/2019    0.965
8/9/2019    0.965
8/12/2019   0.965
```

Comment: Can your initial DataFrame have non-business dates? If so what should happen with them?

Comment: This question is virtually identical to [this previous one of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152785/return-the-consecutive-missing-weekdays-dates-and-assign-rate-next-to-missing-da).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return the consecutive missing weekdays dates and assign rate next to missing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152785/return-the-consecutive-missing-weekdays-dates-and-assign-rate-next-to-missing-da)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`bdate_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.bdate_range.html) to create all the missing values in rates for business days only:

```
new_df = df.set_index('Dates')\
           .reindex( pd.bdate_range(df.Dates.min(), df.Dates.max(), name='Dates'), 
                     method='bfill')\
           .reset_index() 
print (new_df)
        Dates   rates
0  2019-07-26  1.0400
1  2019-07-29  1.0116
2  2019-07-30  1.0116
3  2019-07-31  1.0050
4  2019-08-01  1.0350
5  2019-08-02  1.0100
6  2019-08-05  0.9886
7  2019-08-06  0.9886
8  2019-08-07  0.9650
9  2019-08-08  0.9650
10 2019-08-09  0.9650
11 2019-08-12  0.9650
```

Comment: This is probably the better way to do it. I wasn't sure if the initial DataFrame had non-business days and whether those should be used and retained (in my merge case) or ignored and dropped, as in your case.

Comment: @Ben.T..I am using this code after long time but throwing error '''ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing'''...Any suggestions please..

Comment: @Akash what are the result of `df.Dates.min()` and `df.Dates.max()`? I have the feeling because they are string at the origin, taking the min and the max might be a problematic?

Comment: @Ben T...Thanks. I converted the string into datetime format and it worked. But it generated third column having 'NAN' in all rows. How come that column generated ?

Comment: @Akash on this one I don't see what could cause the column filled of nan, what is the name of the column?

Comment: @Ben.T the output columns are 'Dates, rates and Unnamed: 2'.

Comment: @Akash like this the only time I have seen Unnamed columns is when reading the file, not while using `reindex`. and I don't see why/how this column is created with the current code. sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216748/discussion-between-akash-and-ben-t).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `Series` of all business days then `outer` `merge` and `bfill` the missing values. This will retain any non-business days in your initial DataFrame (if any) and will also use their values in the filling.

```
import pandas as pd
#df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])

s = pd.Series(pd.date_range(df['Dates'].min(), df['Dates'].max(), freq='D'),
              name='Dates')
s = s[s.dt.dayofweek.lt(5)]

df = df.merge(s, how='outer').sort_values('Dates').bfill()
```

---

```
        Dates   rates
0  2019-07-26  1.0400
7  2019-07-29  1.0116
1  2019-07-30  1.0116
2  2019-07-31  1.0050
3  2019-08-01  1.0350
4  2019-08-02  1.0100
8  2019-08-05  0.9886
5  2019-08-06  0.9886
9  2019-08-07  0.9650
10 2019-08-08  0.9650
11 2019-08-09  0.9650
6  2019-08-12  0.9650
```